# Images under the transformation of inversion

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the transformation of inversion $Tz = 1/z$. Find the image of under $T$ of the circle $x^2+y^2=ax$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I guess I am just a bit confused about these types of problems. I do know that Mobius transformations take extended circles to extended circles. So since we are given a circle, to begin with, I expect the image to be a line or circle. I tried converting the equation of the circle to "complex" form so that we would have $|z| = \sqrt{2a(z+\bar{z})}$, whenever $z = x+iy$. However, I don't think this really leads to anything.

Edit: Okay first off thank you for the comments I got lots of insight into this problem. So finding three points on the circle, computing the images, and determining the circle that goes through these images is going to be the image of our circle $x^2+y^2=ax$. Clearly the points $z = 0,a,\frac{a}{2}(1+i)$ all lies on this circle. Computing these images yields:
$$0 \rightarrow \infty \\
a \rightarrow 1/a \\
\frac{a}{2}(1+i) \rightarrow \frac{1}{a}(1-i).$$
The only extended circle that can go through these three points must be a line.

Comment: The "nice" case for inversion is when $z_0\bar{z_0}=r^2+1$ in $|z-z_0|=r$, then by $w=\frac 1z$ it transforms to $|w-\bar{z_0}|=r$.(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3647252/399263) Unfortunately it is not the case here, following the same substitution method I find $\alpha w+\overline{\alpha w}=cst$ for some $\alpha$ meaning we have a line.

Answer (score 3):

How about completing the square to get $(x-a/2)^2+y^2=a^2/4$.  Then since you know you're going to get a circle or a line, check three points.  After all, this is a Mobius transformation.  Or we could express it as $|z-a/2|=|a|/2$.

So $a\mapsto 1/a, 0\mapsto\infty$, and we know we have a line, through $1/a$.

Finally $a/2+a/2i\mapsto (1-i)/a$, and we conclude that it's vertical.

Comment: one of us must be making a mistake, because I find that the image is a straight line. A point $\zeta=u+iv$ lies in the image if and only if for some $z=x+iy$ with $x^2+y^2=ax$, we have $x+iy=z=\frac{1}{\zeta}=\frac{u-iv}{u^2+v^2}$. Or equivalently, $\left(\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-v}{u^2+v^2}\right)^2= \frac{au}{u^2+v^2}$, which implies $u=\frac{1}{a}$ is a straight vertical line.

Comment: @peek-a-boo no, I clearly get two points on the $y$-axis in the image.

Comment: $\pm\frac a{2i}$ do not belong to $|z-\frac a2|=\frac a2$ to start with. I also do get a line by another method.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you're referring to $\frac{a}{2i}\mapsto \frac{-2}{ai}$ and $\frac{-a}{2i}\mapsto \frac{2}{ai}$, then the two points $\frac{a}{2i}$ and $\frac{-a}{2i}$ do not even lie on the circle $x^2+y^2=ax$.

Comment: @zwim I know it can be confusing, maybe I should have used a fraction bar, but I wrote $a/2i$.  Since there are no parentheses, $i$ is in the numerator.

Comment: Well since $\frac 1i=-i$ that changes nothing, your points are NOT on the circle.

Comment: Or I could have written $ai/2$. @zwim

Comment: @zwim you're right. $ (0,0)$ is on it. I made a mistake.

Comment: The only place the circle in the question meets the imaginary axis is at the origin

Comment: So there's the point at infinity.  It's a line after all.   @zwim

Comment: Thanks again for the help on this problem everyone!